# Why Super Saiyan Rose eyes are sometimes pink and sometimes grey?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Super Saiyan Rose eyes are shown to be pink sometimes and other times grey. Is there any reason for this, or it's a design mistake?

[image]

[image]

Comment: To add to the answer, the eyes are pink when powered up because his aura is Pink. Hence the eyes reflecting the pink aura leads to the eye color being animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coloring of Goku black's eyes is pretty inconsistent. It could be a design mistake however, I do not believe it is. My reasoning for the same would be

- The *Grey Eyes* are similar to that of *Zamasu's*. Since Goku Black is basically Zamasu, Goku black's eyes would've intentionally been colored grey.
- If you look at even the *Super Saiyan transformations*, the color of Goku's eyes are Green, blue or red and it depends on the animation/animators of that episode.
- Whenever *Goku Black's eyes are pink*, it is when he's powered up(In the sense, his aura is glowing). So I personally believe it was just incorporated by animators for visual effect

There isn't any factual evidence to precisely answer this question. However, this is the most logical reason I could think off, based on the amount of information available.

Comment: Now that you mention it I've seen regular super saiyan eyes to be blue or green sometimes. But I've never seen them red. Do you have any screencapture or link to a photo where they are shown to be red?

Comment: In toriyama's earlier sketches they were read. Even in some of the Japanese commercials for movies like Cooler's revenge. If you look at one of the early Manga chapters (http://i.imgur.com/UCm5UsX.jpg) , we see Goku's eyes colored red.